# Device got bricked while installing JELLYBEAN

Tags: rom-flashing

I was trying to update my ICS4.0.4 to Jellybean and clear cache partition and also Dalvik cache and unfortunately my tablet got restart and now it is hard bricked just show vendor logo and boot infinitely and now usb debugging was off now anyone please help me to get it unbricked.Thanks in advance. I know last option is to go to vendor service centre don't want to do so.

Now one more thing that if someone can help me to install any android version from starting then all posts are welcomed such as new device with no boot loader. Delete completely and install new boot loader hope you understand what i am saying.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "Clear Cache" and "Wipe Dalvik" shouldn't brick a device, as both only affect temporary data. If your tablet booted during *this* operation (and not during the update process to JB), simply repeat. // Apart from that: Is it *stuck* at the boot screen, or does it boot in a loop? In the latter case, please take a look at our [boot-loop tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info).

Answer (score 0):

with fastboot tools you should still be able to access your device via usb. get the android-sdk-tools from google, and give it a try

[http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_fastboot_intro](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc%3a_fastboot_intro)

http ://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_adb_intro

in this wikis you will also find plenty ways to unbrick your device:

unbrick android xda - Google-Suche
https ://www.google.de/search?q=unbrick+android+xda

Unbrick Any Android Phone
http ://www.beingtricky.com/unbrick-any-android-phone/

These 6 methods will help you unbrick any Android Device - Droidiser
http ://www.droidiser.com/2013/07/how-to-unbrick-any-android-phone.html

FASTBOOT-UNBRICK YOUR DEVICE WITH 'NO DISPLAY' - My Community
http ://forums.droidbeans.com//tutorials/fastboot-to-unbrick-your-device/

xda-developers - Threads Tagged with unbrick
http ://forum.xda-developers.com/tags.php?tag=unbrick

[RELEASE] One-Click UnBrick updated 10july11 - xda-developers
http ://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1153310

hope this will help

Comment: Your answer should not purely rely on links: someone in the future might find this answer and the links will be dead.